# How to get position from grid?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[I want the Pos X and Pos Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhczq.png)

I create several prefabs and I want to know their x and y, that is defined by a Grid Layout Group.

I do:

var newArtist = (GameObject) Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, panel.transform);

Debug.Log(newArtist.transform.position.x + "  " + newArtist.transform.position.y);

It appears 0 0 in all.

Comment: What did you think `new Vector3(0, 0, 0)` was for? The grid layout group doesn't kick in immediately, it has to wait for your code to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newArtist = (GameObject) Instantiate(myPrefab, myPrefab.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, panel.transform);
```